# is it possible to just stream and stop video recording in motion

Tags: motion

My SD card is having limited size and I just want to stream a video so that I can use it as webcam. I successfully did that but problem is it is slow because it keeps saving files as well as does streaming. I donr want to save video files but just stream live in port 8081.
Or is there any alternate streaming app for raspberry pi.
I am using Camera v1 on Raspberry Pi zero.

Comment: Could you set the output file name to /dev/null so it goes nowhere?

Comment: But i think the process will still run athough it may not be able to save.

Comment: But the data is not written to the SD card so it may be quicker.

Comment: @Andyroo Ok thanks. I will try that option.

Comment: That didnt work either. I feel motion does lot of processing. But hopefully I came through this link and I am trying it now https://chriscarey.com/blog/2017/04/30/achieving-high-frame-rate-with-a-raspberry-pi-camera-system/ .

Comment: How about trying the movie_output https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html#movie_output setting?  Not sure if this allows streaming and I’ve no camera cable handy to test for you today (no idea where it is - have Pi and camera free just no cable arrrrgggg).

Comment: @Andyroo Thanks. I will have a look today and get back to you.

Comment: "is there any alternate streaming app?" - and which one are you using now?

Comment: Nothing is working. Also I tried to give gap between motion detection to 60000 where default is 60 and also movie time just 1 sec from default value of infinite. Still it is slow.